# Trouble with Index error in Google Appengine Python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, indexing

We are having a Google appengine Python application, and it's running for the past 1.5 Years.
We use the out of the box NoSQL DB in our Python application.

But all of a sudden, we are getting Index related errors. We have deleted and re-installed the index multiple times, but after "Building" it reaches the "Error" state automatically. Need help in debugging it.

**Anatomy of the Index:**

The index contains 2 StringListProperty fields, 1 date object, 1 string, 1 boolean and 1 Float objects.
The same fields are also used in other indexes, and those indices seem to be working fine. If you look at the snapshot from the admin console (given below), it shows a few other indices that are working fine.

```
- kind: UserRideRequests
  properties:
  - name: date_of_start
  - name: end_cells
  - name: is_cancelled
  - name: request_type
  - name: start_cells
  - name: time_of_start_as_number
```

2 images below - Indexes, and Datastore statistics.

[image: Error shown in application console]

[image: Datastore statistics]

Comment: From your description of an error that occurs "at random", it sounds like some sort of concurrency issue. Have you considered the fact that some DB operations are not atomic, and when several instances of your application on GAE attempt to access the DB simultaneously, the DB is left in a non-deterministic state (which eventually leads to the error that you've mentioned)? In addition, are you absolutely sure that your application is 100% stateless (no variables "in memory", everything stored into and loaded from the DB)?

Comment: You should decorate the methods that must ensure DB atomic operations with `@db.transactional`.

Comment: @barakmanos Thanks for the suggestions. Let me try it. Yeah we are 100% stateless. We do not cache any elements. If ever we want to cache something in memory, we use "Memcache" .

Comment: What about the atomicity of your DB operations?